# TableView as seen in "Addresses"

Tags: iphone, uitableview

every iPhone and iPod Touch has got the Apple "Addresses" App ... when you create a new record, there is a tableview. The first line contains an button (to add an image) and a tableview cell.
How would I do such a tableview cell with a button and a regular cell in one row ?

Thanks a lot !
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a button and a regular cell. It's one custom cell with two custom subviews the second of which is made to look like a standard tableview cell.

Just make a tableview cell that looks like you want (either in interface builder or programmatically) and return it as the cell for section 0, row 0.